# Como formatar datas no Adonisjs?

Tags: javascript, adonisjs

Como posso mandar datas formatadas em DD-MM-YYYY pro banco n Adonisjs?

```
class AtendimentoSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('atendimentos', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.date('data_emissao')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('atendimentos')
  }
}
```

Comment: O [Migration](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/migration) não oferece esse tipo de flexibilização pois é muito limitado. Você tem que formatar as datas no [Lucid Models](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/lucid#_dates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve formatar a data utilizando o lucid models e não o migration.

Para isso no model faça o seguinte:

```
class User extends Model {
  static get dates () {
    return super.dates.concat(['data_emissao'])
  }

  static formatDates (field, value) {
    if (field === 'data_emissao') {
      return value.format('DD-MM-YYYY')
    }
    return super.formatDates(field, value)
  }
}
```

É só adaptar para o seu model e caso queira saber mais leia a documentação abaixo.

https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/lucid#_formatting_date_fields

Comment: Bom dia. Obrigado por responder. Fiz a alteração no meu model de Atendimento com o codigo citado. Mas ainda continua salvando no formato YYYY-DD-MM.
Meu retorn JSON
```
{
  "data_emissao": "2020-02-20",
  "created_at": "2020-02-27 10:59:36",
  "updated_at": "2020-02-27 10:59:36",
  "id": 1
```

Comment: como vc ta salvando no banco? esta usando lucid? o banco que esta usando aceita no campo o formato DD-MM-YYYY ?

Comment: const atendimento = new Atendimento();

   atendimento.data_emissao = request.input('data_emissao')

   
  

    await atendimento.save()

    return atendimento;

Comment: O método  formatDates é chamado antes de salvar a instância do modelo no banco de dados. Portanto, verifique se o valor de retorno é sempre um formato válido para o mecanismo de banco de dados que você está usando.

Comment: esta se referindo à view?
Estou utilizando o input de data do html5 normal.

Caso se refira ao tipo da migration, estou usando o tipo Date (Ja tentei com datetime tambem)

table.date('data_emissao')

Comment: estou me referindo ao model, como o augusto disse acima não se formata data na migration, no model utilizando o código que mencionei acima formata a data, agora vc tem que verificar se o seu banco de dados aceita o formato desejado, por exemplo o padrão do mysql é YYYY-MM-DD e não DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: Complementei a resposta para seu campo `data_emissao` ser compreendido pelo adonis como um campo do tipo data.

Comment: Tudo o que voces me passaram estava correto para funcionar. Porem eu dava rollback e as modificações nao funcionavam
Eu deletei o banco e rodei migration:run novamente e tudo esta retornando com a data formatada na minha view. Nao faço ideia do que pode ter acontecido, mas obrigado. Me ajudaram muito. Até mais